# I am getting an error when declaring variables in VBA

Tags: vba, variable-declaration

I'm trying to declare two variables with the values of each one, but there is an error "Declaration expected" in the lines where I assing the values of c and e. Why is this happening ? Am I declaring the variables wrong?

```
   Dim c As Integer

   Dim e As Integer

   c = 0

   e = 0
```

Thanks a lot for your feedback

Comment: That's your whole code, in a single module?

Comment: For the second part; No, you are not declaring them wrong. Normally this would even work without declaring, unless using `Option Explicit`. But you should always declare them, and using `Option Explicit` is a good idea too.

Comment: `Declaration expected`: "A nondeclarative statement, such as an assignment or loop statement, occurs outside any procedure. Only declarations are allowed outside procedures."  -   "A procedure is a block of Visual Basic statements enclosed by a declaration statement (Function, Sub, Operator, Get, Set) and a matching End declaration. All executable statements in Visual Basic must be within some procedure."

Comment: @TimWilliams No, actually this is only the first Form1, what i'm trying to do is to create two variables that store the values and modify them with other forms (In this case we are talking about 15 Forms.vb), and the last step after all the forms execute would be to display the final result of e and c.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the variables outside a procedure to give them module-wide scope but you can't assign a value to them outside a procedure. Therefore this is correct.

```
Dim c As Integer
Dim e As Integer

Sub MyProcedure()

   c = 0                 ' the value is zero by default
   e = 0
End Sub
```

and this is correct, too.

```
Sub MyProcedure()

   Dim c As Integer
   Dim e As Integer

   c = 0                 ' the value is zero by default
   e = 0
End Sub
```

In the latter case the variables cannot be used in other procedures in the same module without again being declared there locally.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Variatus, i'm gonna give it a shot, cause seems kinda weird the error that i'm getting

Answer (score 0):

Place the variables in a separate code module, and declare them as *Public*:

```vb
Public c As Integer
Public e As Integer
```

They will default to the value 0 (zero).

Now you can assign them values from any form or code module.

Comment: Declaring the variables as `Public` will enlarge their scope to the entire project. Scope doesn't appear to be the problem here.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks a lot for the option, gonna give it a try too